# Trying to create a new table column using reference table value under certain conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, create-table

Right now I have two data tables in the form:

```
library(dplyr)

> lengths 
chrom    p      q
1        2560   78934
2        1346   9087
3        678    7809
4        5467   1253
...

> my_data
mut      pos       chr    arm
A        567       2      p
B        6890      2      q
C        978       3      q
D        4689      4      p
...
```

I want to add another column `my_data$chrom.pos`, that is conditionally adding values from `lengths$q` to the `my_data$pos` values IF `my_data$arm` is 'p', but not 'q'.

What I have thus far:

```
my_data %>% mutate(chrom.pos =
                       case_when (arm == "q" ~ pos,
                                  arm == "p" ~ pos + lengths[["q"]][chr])
  )
```

While this handles the 'q' condition just fine, any case that is 'p' comes out as NA because I'm not getting the linking quite right.

```
> my_data
mut      pos       chr    arm    chrom.pos
A        567       2      p      NA        # Looking for 9087 + 567 = 9654
B        6890      2      q      6890
C        978       3      q      978
D        4689      4      p      NA        # Looking for 1253 + 4689 = 5942
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge two data with `chr` and `chrom` as keys.

```r
library(dplyr)

my_data %>%
  left_join(select(lengths, chrom, q), by = c("chr" = "chrom")) %>%
  mutate(chrom.pos = if_else(arm == "p", pos + q, pos)) %>%
  select(-q)

#   mut  pos chr arm chrom.pos
# 1   A  567   2   p      9654
# 2   B 6890   2   q      6890
# 3   C  978   3   q       978
# 4   D 4689   4   p      5942
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason this couldn't work could be because of leading/lagging spaces in the 'arm' column values.  We can remove those spaces with `trimws` and it should work

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% 
     mutate(pos = trimws(pos), 
         chrom.pos =
                       case_when (arm == "q" ~ pos,
                                  arm == "p" ~ pos + lengths[["q"]][chr])
  )
```